# Create list of map items in dart

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart

I am trying to initialize a jsonarray (list of maps) in dart using the following code.

```
// var faqList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
var faqItem = <String, dynamic>{
  "title": 'Core Ideas',
  "content": [
    "ABC",
    "BCA",
    "YZX"
  ]
};

List<Map<String, dynamic>> faqList = [faqItem];
faqList+=[faqItem];
faqList.add(faqItem);
```

However, i am not able to add an item to the list using `add`. It gives me an error saying faqList is already defined. How do I add more maps to the list ?

[image]

Comment: perhaps the error will be `faqList.add("faqItem");`, try to check if there are any other places you've defined the same variable, it can be on different files with import section

Comment: no i have noto defined it anywhere, the 4 lines pasted above is giving the error

Comment: try to restart the IDE,

Comment: restarting did not fix it. i changed the variable name from `faqList` to `abclist` and it gave me the same error

Comment: how about put this snippet to another file, if same issue your pc might need some rest :D

Comment: Please post a *complete* example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: it is a complete snippet, you don't need anything else to reproduce

Comment: @VipinVerma It is not a complete snippet.  There is no `main` function.  I cannot copy and paste the code exactly as written and run it to reproduce the problem.  If the code posted is intended to be the body of the `main` function, then I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using inside statefulWidget try this

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final faqItem = <String, dynamic>{
    'title': 'Core Ideas',
    'content': ['ABC', 'BCA', 'YZX']
  };

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> faqList = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    faqList.add(faqItem);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

In case of a static class:

```
class Faq {
  static final faqItem = <String, dynamic>{
    'title': 'Core Ideas',
    'content': ['ABC', 'BCA', 'YZX']
  };
  static final List<Map<String, dynamic>> faqList = [faqItem,faqItem2,...];


  static void addItem(Map<String, dynamic> faqItem) {
    faqList.add(faqItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: i was doing this in a static dart file composed of static data.